# Change accesskey modifier keys in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, menubar

I'm working on a website where each page has buttons, like "submit" and "cancel". Each of these buttons has an `accesskey` attribute. The submit button's `accesskey` attribute is set to `S`, and the cancel button's `accesskey` attribute is set to `C`.

Access keys are activated using different modifiers in different browsers. Internet Explorer, Safari, and Google Chrome use just the <kbd>alt</kbd>, while Firefox uses both the <kbd>alt</kbd> and the <kbd>shift</kbd> keys. As well, Firefox uses <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to open the history menu.

Answers to this question should not suggest changing settings in the browser's configuration as that would not be feasible on a production site.

How I change the modifier keys that Firefox uses for `accesskey`'s to just <kbd>alt</kbd>, and prevent the history menu from opening?

I am working in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If the existing answers don't answer your question, please explain _how_, keeping in mind that not everything is possible, and if this isn't, that's a valid answer.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes the existing answers is not working firefox browser in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: please give me a suitable solution

Comment: This question is not working.

Comment: If that ^ wasn't particularly helpful, maybe now you understand what I mean by "clarify". "not working" isn't a problem description./

Answer (score 8):

You cannot—as far as I can tell—change the key combination required to activate an `accesskey`, but what you're trying to achieve does not require use of the `accesskey` attribute. You can listen for the keydown event directly.

Add a keydown event listener to the document. In the handler function check to see if the alt and s keys are pressed. If they are—and no other modifier keys are pressed—prevent the default action of the event, then trigger a click event on the submit button.Triggering the click event on the submit button will in turn trigger the submit event listener, whereas [triggering the submit event on the form directly may not.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit')

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  // If the only modifier key is the alt key, and the s key is pressed
  if(!e.metaKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && e.altKey && e.key === 's') {
    e.preventDefault()  // Prevent the mozilla history menu from opening
    submit.click()      // Trigger the form submission
  }
})
```

```html
<form action=""><button type="submit" id="submit"><u>S</u>ubmit</button></form>
```

<sub>**Notes**:</sub>
<sub>1. Though this works in the current stable version of Firefox, I have not tested other versions</sub>
<sub>2. This example uses language features introduced in the 2015 version of [The ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). These features are not required to achieve the desired effect, but make the code easier to read. If you need to support older browsers, you can use `var` instead of `const`, and a standard function instead of the fat arrow function.</sub>
<sub>3. Unfortunately—due to sandboxing—the Stack Overflow snippet feature does not work for this example, see this [example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/haqote/5/edit?js,console,output) instead</sub>

Comment: Answer is not working firefox browser in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @bobmarti you'll have to include a reproducible example of it not working in firefox on ubuntu, because the example above does in fact work for me in firefox on ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

If you want deep knowledge about it then try this article has more info: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Ui.key.contentAccess

If you find that you can't get used to the "in-tab" preferences dialog, there is a preference to return to the old style dialog:

1. In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and
   press Enter. Click the button promising to be careful.
2. In the search box above the list, type or paste pref and pause while
   the list is filtered
3. Double-click the browser.preferences.inContent preference to switch
   it from true to false

**Note:** I don't know whether that will be in Firefox forever or is a transitional feature.

Comment: i give some details about of my question.i don't want to change anything in about:config.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I opened about:config, then wrote
ui.key.contentAccess = 6, where 6 = 2 (Ctrl) + 4 (Alt). 
Now I can use Ctrl + Alt in order to access shortcuts in Wikipedia.
See Wikipedia:Keyboard shortcuts https://w.wiki/Trm